# How should i draw these DFAs?

Tags: dfa

I have to draw these 2 DFA,but i don't understand what logic should i follow.Before that,there were some easier,i got them.But these...
so the first is:

Σ={c,z}

L={W∈Σ* | w contain this:"czccz"}

I know that i have to draw 5circles with(c,cz,czc,czcc and czccz), but after that i have no idea how should i draw arrows and loops.Here is the next one.

Σ={a,m}

L={W∈Σ* | w NOT contain this:"ammam"}

If you can reccomend me some pages,where i can practise these,I would be very grateful.

This is my attempt:

[image: My attempt]

Comment: As far as DFAs go, these are very simple problems so if you're having trouble you probably need to review your course material and get help from other students. For the first example, how do you get from the start state to `c`? How do you go from `c` to `cz`? What happens when you're in state `c` and the next input is a `c`? Each state and input pair is a simple decision, and there are only 12 total decisions you need to make. Do you have a problem making those decisions, or is the problem more fundamental (i.e., do you not understand how this breaks down to 12 transitions)?

Comment: so-so.
Here is my attempt( https://ibb.co/Qf1N8dK ).I try to follow these steps what i saw in the pdf(what we got).

Comment: That's definitely not correct. For example, the string "czzc" leads to state `czcc` which is accepting. "czzc" is not in the language. You seem to have many transitions backward. Start with the string "czccz" as this is the defining string for the DFA, and then add the other transitions.

Comment: i try it,but i dont find any logic in this.I have no idea how should i solve it.

Comment: Finally,the first DFA is okay.I try to solve the second,but it will be hard.

Comment: The second is identical to the first, just with the accepting/non-accepting states flipped when you're done. Solve for the language of all strings containing "ammam" and then reverse the accepting states.

Comment: FINALLY,i can solve it.Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your question is to find a DFA for a string in which it contains "czccz" as substring  and the alphabet is (c,z). You can check your solution in the image provided.

[image: picture reference]